# CD\ Command Line in MS DOS

Tags: windows, cmd.exe

When I try `CD\` from Our Map Drive I get:

> error :'cd\' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>   operable program or batch file.

But with space (`cd \`) it s working ,

`T:\bat>cd\`

> 'cd\' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>   operable program or batch file.

`T:\bat>cd \`

`T:\>`

Could anyone tell me why this is?

Comment: Works fine without the space on a mapped network share on Windows 7. What exactly is the problem?

Comment: `cmd.exe` is not the same as MS-DOS

Answer (score 2):

`CmdPi`'s answer repeats the received wisdom that Microsoft's command interpreters work like UNIX shells.  This is the way that everyone voted with their feet in the 1980s.  But in fact they didn't and still don't.

*Command names* could and can be separated from *command tails* by a fair number of characters, not solely by whitespace.  One can use the equals character, for example, or the comma.  `path=C:\DOS` is a command and a tail.  So too is `dir,dos`. Most famously, one can use the full stop.  Hence the well-known `echo.` trick for echoing a blank line in a command script.  What is less well known is that `echo;`, `echo+`, `echo=`, `echo(`, `echo,`, `echo[`, `echo]`, `echo\`, and `echo/` will all do the same (albeit not always for some of them).

In fact, there's a DOS API call (`int 21h,ax=6505h`) that can be used to obtain the complete list of characters that are so-called "filename termination characters".  And DOS command interpreters use it to determine what characters terminate a command name and begin the command tail.  (Microsoft command interpreters for non-DOS operating systems probably just hardwire the set of characters.)

The backslash is one of those characters, and in command interpreters from Microsoft's `command` in MS-DOS to Microsoft's `cmd` in Windows NT (including IBM's/Microsoft's `cmd` for OS/2 along the way) one can execute `cd\` and the result will be that the command interpreter changes directory to `\`.  Whether the termination character is included in the command tail actually varies from command to command.  With the `cd` command it is.  With the `dir` and `path` commands it is not.  (Yes, the command-line parser in Microsoft command interpreters behaves differently according to what built-in command is to be run.)

This has never really been documented, though.  As I said: most people voted with their feet in the 1980s to embrace the UNIX shell paradigm, even though things like argument parsing and quoting are a vast conspiratorial fiction implemented not by the command interpreter at all but by the runtime libraries of several programming language implementations for DOS; and you'll find that most of the literature states with confidence that whitespace separates name from tail, even though it isn't actually true.  `echo.` is usually described a quirk and a trick, and very rarely described as simply one case of an overall syntax that Microsoft's command interpreters have employed for roughly three decades.

I recommend following the 1980s trend here, and not relying upon this little-known syntax.  Use whitespace.  It's what people document.  It's what the likes of IBM and Microsoft themselves document.  It's what folk wisdom states to be the case.  It's what the UNIX-heads expect.  ☺

My command interpreter went with the syntax charts and descriptions that are in the IBM doco.  However, you'll find that FreeCOM implements this little-documented behaviour, as do JP Software's command interpreters and the `command` from OpenDOS.  JP Software's doco recommends using space and describes using other termination characters as "illegal".  It is, however, one of the few places that actually states in official documentation that there's an alternative to be had.

### Further reading

- Jonathan de Boyne Pollard (2010).  [*Differences from other command interpreters*](http://homepage.ntlworld.com/jonathan.deboynepollard/Softwares/cmd/guide/differences.html).  32-Bit Command Interpreter User Guide.
- ["Command Names and Parameters"](http://jpsoft.com/help/cmdnames.htm).  TCC/Take Command Help.  JP Software.
- ['lib/is_fnamec.c`](http://sourceforge.net/p/freedos/svn/HEAD/tree/freecom/trunk/lib/is_fnamc.c).  FreeCOM Source.  SourceForge.
- ['shell/command.c`](http://sourceforge.net/p/freedos/svn/HEAD/tree/freecom/trunk/shell/command.c).  FreeCOM Source.  SourceForge.

Comment: Nice answer, but to the wrong question. This has nothing to do with this question.

Answer (score 1):

CD is a command, \ a parameter.

You have to separate both with a space.

Comment: That isn't strictly true. At least in windows 7 and beyond you do not need to separate them. At some point prior you did, but I can't remember which version of windows implemented the change.

Comment: its working in different Drive                                         Microsoft Windows XP [Version 6.1.7601]
(C) Copyright 1985-2001 Microsoft Corp.

U:\bat>cd\

U:\>

Comment: Having said that, it is not particularly onerous to simply use the space at all times to maintain backwards compatibility.

Comment: also tested in Win XP ,7 and 8

Comment: My only guess (and this is pure guess) is that it has to do with the mapping of the drive. The command prompt has never liked unc paths at all and I suspect that even though the drive is mapped it still treats it as a different (read reduced capability) drive system.

Comment: it s related with rights on related map drive

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, this was never changed in any MS-DOS or Windows version. While I don't know whether it was considered "legal", it was always possible to omit the space. I am sure for MS-DOS 3.3, 5.0, 6.0, 6.22, and Windows 95, 98, 98SE, ME, XP (all SPs), 7, 8, and 10. This is why it took me some time getting used to linux at first...